# Administration Of EhCahe

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

Is there any common JSP or page that can provide functionality to see the caches names, their size or contents or provide option to delete elements from cache or remove all elements from cache.

If not all functionality one or more is fine. I can add the rest.

Answer (score 0):

EHCache provides administration trough web console and REST API in their enterprise version. Details can be [found here.](http://ehcache.org/documentation/jmx.html)

Underneath JMX is used. Below two links provide information on enabling JMX. Once it is enabled, you can use the JMX console that comes with AppServer or use an open source console like [MX4J](http://mx4j.sourceforge.net/)

- http://onjavahell.blogspot.com/2009/09/monitoring-ehcache-with-jmx-and-spring.html
- http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/11159
- http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/4316.page

Comment: Its a full fledged application. Needs to deploy one more application. My need is simple. See the size of the cache and clear cache. Should be able to do with simple JSP.

Comment: @pojg - then all you need to do is create your own jsp that works with the JMX beans exposed by EHCache. Accept this as the answer if this is what you are looking for